# splitting code on to separate pages in a worksheet

Tags: minipage, pgfmath, xlop

I am trying to split the following code onto 3 separate pages, as in page one being the question, page two the working and the third being the answers. but I can only seem to get it with all three on consecutive rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
%AdditionCode
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\usepackage{xlop}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{~\\56 Problem Practice Worksheet}
\rhead{Name: ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ \\}
\lfoot{Number Correct: ~ \Large $\dfrac{~}{20}$}
\cfoot{~}


\newcommand*{\DifficultyOne}{999}%
\newcommand*{\DifficultyTwo}{99}%
%---------------------------------------%
\newcommand{\AddQuestion}[1]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%

  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnea}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoa}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneb}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwob}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnec}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoc}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOned}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwod}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnee}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoe}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnef}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwof}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneg}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwog}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneh}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoh}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}

  \hspace*{\fill}
  \opadd[carryadd=false, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOnea} {\AddTwoa} \hfill  \opadd[carryadd=false, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOneb}{\AddTwob} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=false, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOnec}{\AddTwoc} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=false, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOned}{\AddTwod} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=false, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOnee}{\AddTwoe} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=false, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOnef}{\AddTwof} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=false, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOneg}{\AddTwog} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=false, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOneh}{\AddTwoh}  \hspace*{\fill}\\
  ~\newline
  ~\newline
  
   \hspace*{\fill}
  \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOnea} {\AddTwoa} \hfill  \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOneb}{\AddTwob} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOnec}{\AddTwoc} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOned}{\AddTwod} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOnee}{\AddTwoe} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOnef}{\AddTwof} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOneg}{\AddTwog} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOneh}{\AddTwoh}  \hspace*{\fill}\\
  ~\newline
  ~\newline
  
   \hspace*{\fill}
  \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{black}]{\AddOnea} {\AddTwoa} \hfill  \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{black}]{\AddOneb}{\AddTwob} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{black}]{\AddOnec}{\AddTwoc} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{black}]{\AddOned}{\AddTwod} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{black}]{\AddOnee}{\AddTwoe} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{black}]{\AddOnef}{\AddTwof} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{black}]{\AddOneg}{\AddTwog} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{black}]{\AddOneh}{\AddTwoh}  \hspace*{\fill}\\
  ~\newline
  ~\newline

    }%
    }%

    \begin{document}

    \vspace{2cm}

    \AddQuestion{5}

    \end{document}
```

I was trying minipage but have been unsuccessful

Comment: Here (TeX Live 2022) your code doesn't compile because of line 7. If I remove it, compilation works fine. As for your problem, did you try `\newpage` between the parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Try this code.

The code was simplified to avoid repetitions.
Each line of 8 problems is generated by ;

```
\OneXLine{<true or false>}{<result color>}
```

The first argument controls the carry-add (true or false); the second the color of the answer.

The new page is issued after completing n-lines x 8 problems/working/answers.

The numbers used for each problem are random, but the same numbers are reused in  "working" and "answers" by choosing the same seed for each set.

To make a different set of worksheets, an integer is added to the seed and serves to identify the build. For reference, that number is printed in the right footer.

This allows the same build to be reproduced on a later occasion if needed.

[image: d]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
    
\usepackage{xlop}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{~\\48 Problem Practice Worksheet}
\rhead{Name: ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ \\}
\lfoot{Number Correct: ~ \Large $\dfrac{~}{48}$}
\cfoot{~}
\rfoot{Ref:~\theRandSeed}% identify the worksheet <<<<<
    
\newcommand*{\DifficultyOne}{999}%
\newcommand*{\DifficultyTwo}{99}%

\newcounter{RandSeed}       
\setcounter{RandSeed}{6} % choose an integer random seed for this build of problems and answers <<<<<   

%%  \OneXLine{<true or false>}{<result color>}  
\newcommand{\OneXline}[2]{% one line of 8 problems, workings or answers
\hspace*{\fill}
\opadd[carryadd=#1, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{#2}]{\AddOnea} {\AddTwoa} \hfill
\opadd[carryadd=#1, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{#2}]{\AddOneb}{\AddTwob} \hfill
\opadd[carryadd=#1, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{#2}]{\AddOnec}{\AddTwoc} \hfill
\opadd[carryadd=#1, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{#2}]{\AddOned}{\AddTwod} \hfill
\opadd[carryadd=#1, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{#2}]{\AddOnee}{\AddTwoe} \hfill 
\opadd[carryadd=#1, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{#2}]{\AddOnef}{\AddTwof} \hfill 
\opadd[carryadd=#1, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{#2}]{\AddOneg}{\AddTwog} \hfill
\opadd[carryadd=#1, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{#2}]{\AddOneh}{\AddTwoh}
\hspace*{\fill}\\
}

\newcommand{\GenerateRandom}{%  %   \GenerateRandom
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnea}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoa}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneb}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwob}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnec}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoc}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOned}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwod}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnee}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoe}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnef}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwof}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneg}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwog}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneh}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoh}{random(\DifficultyTwo)} 
}
    
%---------------------------------------% 
\newcommand{\AddQuestion}[1]{%

    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{% 
        \pgfmathsetseed{\i+\value{RandSeed}}
        \GenerateRandom
        \OneXline{false}{white}
        ~\newline
        ~\newline
    }
    
    \newpage% added <<<<<<<<<<      
    
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%
        \pgfmathsetseed{\i+\value{RandSeed}}
        \GenerateRandom
        \OneXline{true}{white}  
        ~\newline
    }
    \newpage% added <<<<<<<<<<          
    
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%
        \pgfmathsetseed{\i+\value{RandSeed}}
        \GenerateRandom
        \OneXline{true}{black}
        ~\newline
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
    \AddQuestion{6}     % 6 lines of 10 problems
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @SimonDispa this works to separate the three steps but I only prints one line per page instead of a whole worksheet, any Ideas?

Comment: @Paul A Please see the updated answer.